# How to get all items under certain conditions in DynamoDbAsyncTable

Tags: java, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb

I want to get all the items that are bigger than the sortValue(createdTime)

data
[image]

gameUid = partitionKey

cratedTime = sortKey

```
val dynamoTable: DynamoDbAsyncTable

val key = Key.builder()
        .partitionValue("02a6c002-d6cc-4327-9398-545a956e01e7").sortValue(1).build()

    val queryConditional =
        QueryConditional.sortGreaterThan(key)

    dynamoTable.query(queryConditional)
        .items()
        .subscribe {
            println("queryTest $it")
        }.join()
```

result

```
Game(
gameUid = 02a6c002-d6cc-4327-9398-545a956e01e7, 
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
createdTime=1644005720324, 
userUid=4w9xNSYn4dQGbLXk0AjP2nzOVJm2
)
```

```
//not working
val key = Key.builder()
        .partitionValue("gameUid").sortValue(1).build()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just query for one partition at a time, which will work as below

```
val key = Key.builder()
        .partitionValue("02a6c002-d6cc-4327-9398-545a956e01e7").sortValue(1).build()
```

But if you want to get all the values greater than `createdTime` regardless of the partition then you have to scan the table as described [FilterExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.FilterExpression)

Also look at [Key.Builder](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/Key.Builder.html) for more details for your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't I use SQL? It's useless. Simple query requires too many codes.

Solution

```
    val attVal = AttributeValue.builder()
        .n("1644005720324")
        .build()

    val myMap: MutableMap<String, AttributeValue> = HashMap()
    myMap[":val1"] = attVal

    val myExMap: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
    myExMap["#createdTime"] = "createdTime"

    val expression = Expression.builder()
        .expressionValues(myMap)
        .expressionNames(myExMap)
        .expression("#createdTime > :val1")
        .build()

    val enhancedRequest = ScanEnhancedRequest.builder()
        .filterExpression(expression)
        .limit(15)
        .build()

    dynamoTable.scan(enhancedRequest).items().subscribe {
        println("queryTest!! $it")
    }.join()
```

result

```
queryTest!! Game(gameUid=79310a7b-d2ac-47b2-907a-c2fa08a2dd6f, numbers=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], createdTime=1644005720942, userUid=4w9xNSYn4dQGbLXk0AjP2nzOVJm2)

queryTest!! Game(gameUid=42e9579d-d897-4925-8a64-a388c9647133, numbers=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], createdTime=1644005721555, userUid=4w9xNSYn4dQGbLXk0AjP2nzOVJm2)
```

update, use global secondary index

```
    val key = Key.builder()
        .partitionValue(userUidString).sortValue(createdTime).build()
    val queryConditional = QueryConditional.sortLessThanOrEqualTo(key)

    dynamoTable.index("userUid-createdTime-index")
        .query(queryConditional)
        .map {
            it.items()
        }.subscribe {
            gameList.addAll(it)
        }.join()
```